# Eigenvalues on sympy giving piecewise values

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm trying to calculate some eigenvalues of a symbolic matrix, but as eigenvalues I'm getting a set of really large values with conditionals. I was going later to expand and take only values until k^2 to simplify.

The Matrix is the following

```
l, k, t, k1,k2 = sp.symbols('l k t k_1 k_2', real=True)
#k1 = k*sp.cos(t)
#k2 = k*sp.sin(t)
M2 = sp.Matrix([[(k1**2 + k2**2)*l**2 ,-sp.I*l*k1,-sp.I*l*k2,0],
               [-sp.I*l*k1, sp.Rational(1) + (k1**2)*2*l**2,k1*k2*2*l**2,l*k1],
               [-sp.I*l*k2,k1*k2*2*l**2,sp.Rational(1) + (k2**2)*2*l**2,-l*k2],
               [0,l*k1,-l*k2,sp.Rational(2)-(k1**2 + k2**2)*l**2]])
M2

M2.eigenvals()
```

I have tried with this trigonometric simplification but it doesn't help either. I don't know exactly what is happening, because I thoutgh that everything was well defined.

I have a dictionary with four elements, each one of then, with some variations, is like: (HUGE)

```
{Piecewise((k_1**2/2 + k_2**2/2 - sqrt(2*k_1**4/3 + 4*k_1**2*k_2**2/3 - 16*k_1**2/3 + 2*k_2**4/3 - 16*k_2**2/3 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/4 - 2*(-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**(1/3) - 10/3)/2 + sqrt(4*k_1**4/3 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2/3 - 32*k_1**2/3 + 4*k_2**4/3 - 32*k_2**2/3 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/2 + 2*(-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**(1/3) - 20/3 + (4*k_1**6 + 12*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 12*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 16*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 20*k_1**2 + 4*k_2**6 - 20*k_2**2 + 2*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 4)/sqrt(2*k_1**4/3 + 4*k_1**2*k_2**2/3 - 16*k_1**2/3 + 2*k_2**4/3 - 16*k_2**2/3 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/4 - 2*(-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**(1/3) - 10/3))/2 + 1, Eq(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12, 0)), (k_1**2/2 + k_2**2/2 - sqrt(2*k_1**4/3 + 4*k_1**2*k_2**2/3 - 16*k_1**2/3 + 2*k_2**4/3 - 16*k_2**2/3 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/4 + 2*(sqrt((-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**2/4 + (2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)**3/27) + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/216 - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/6 + (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/16)**(1/3) - 10/3 - 2*(2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)/(3*(sqrt((-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**2/4 + (2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)**3/27) + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/216 - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/6 + (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/16)**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(4*k_1**4/3 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2/3 - 32*k_1**2/3 + 4*k_2**4/3 - 32*k_2**2/3 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/2 - 2*(sqrt((-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**2/4 + (2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)**3/27) + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/216 - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/6 + (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/16)**(1/3) - 20/3 + (4*k_1**6 + 12*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 12*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 16*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 20*k_1**2 + 4*k_2**6 - 20*k_2**2 + 2*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 4)/sqrt(2*k_1**4/3 + 4*k_1**2*k_2**2/3 - 16*k_1**2/3 + 2*k_2**4/3 - 16*k_2**2/3 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/4 + 2*(sqrt((-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**2/4 + (2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)**3/27) + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/216 - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/6 + (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/16)**(1/3) - 10/3 - 2*(2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)/(3*(sqrt((-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**2/4 + (2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)**3/27) + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/216 - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/6 + (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/16)**(1/3))) + 2*(2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)/(3*(sqrt((-(-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/108 + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/3 - (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/8)**2/4 + (2*k_1**6 + 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 - k_1**4 + 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - k_2**4 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2) - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**2/12)**3/27) + (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)**3/216 - (-k_1**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 8*k_1**2 - k_2**4 + 8*k_2**2 - 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 + 5)*(-2*k_1**6 - 14*k_1**4*k_2**2 + k_1**4 - 14*k_1**2*k_2**4 - 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 + 4*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**6 + k_2**4 + 4*k_2**2 - (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**6/2 + 3*k_1**4*k_2**2/2 + 3*k_1**2*k_2**4/2 + 2*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 5*k_1**2/2 + k_2**6/2 - 5*k_2**2/2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/16 + k_1**2*k_2**2/8 - k_1**2/2 + k_2**4/16 - k_2**2/2 + 3*(-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/256 - 5/16) - 1/2))/6 + (2*k_1**6 + 6*k_1**4*k_2**2 + 6*k_1**2*k_2**4 + 8*k_1**2*k_2**2 - 10*k_1**2 + 2*k_2**6 - 10*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)*(k_1**4/2 + k_1**2*k_2**2 - 4*k_1**2 + k_2**4/2 - 4*k_2**2 + (-2*k_1**2 - 2*k_2**2 - 4)**2/8 - 5/2) - 2)**2/16)**(1/3)))/2 + 1, True)): 1,
```

And it is basically an expression, followed by an (Eq,) statement. Does anyone know what is happening ? I know that in mathematica this is working, someone did it there.

Comment: The eigenvalues of that matrix are the roots of a fourth-order polynomial. It's a very messy expression, and Sympy is probably not able to handle it.

The polynomial is of the form: f(x) = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + x^4 (I checked with Mathematica). Each one of the coefficients depend on k1, k2, and l.

So if you really want a symbolic expression, you could derive the characteristic polynomial, and express the eigenvalues in terms of the roots of that polynomial.